# mobile html5 videos using sprites

Tags: html, mobile, video, sprite, mobile-website

The new FB paper app [website](http://facebook.com/paper) has html5 videos when seen from a non-mobile device.
A video like effect is achieved on the [mobile website](https://m.facebook.com/paper) (tried on iOS browsers) using some kind of weird sprites.
Does anybody know how to implement that?

Comment: It's just a video element. View the page source and you will see it - here's one video from that webpage http://dragon.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/t39.2365/851558_1389078601354955_205775253_n.mp4

Comment: @Dipaks, on the mobile website looks like it's not a video see [this example](https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/t39.2365/851547_133891700114933_1761018918_n.jpg)

Comment: @Dipaks, also if you know a way to play video backgrounds in iOS browsers I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: Interesting! Haven't seen it on mobile - I will check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that used a method originally used by Apple.
Take a look at [this](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1GWTMLjqQsQS45FWwqNG9ztQTdGF48hQYpjQHR_d1WsI)